# KQL Query to show installed kb monthly updates

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer

I've been trying and failing/falling down a rabbit hole trying to output a table showing vms and monthly KBs install status as columns.
I've tried both Join and Union but in the case of Join I just get all as installed and when I use Union I don't see the expected data.

[desired output]

[image]

Attempted queries 1:

```
let AUGUPDATES =
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | where KBID == "5029242"
    | project Computer, Aug_Installed=UpdateState;
let SEPTUPDATES =
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | where KBID == "5030213"
    | project Computer, Sep_Installed=UpdateState;
let OCTUPDATES =
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | where KBID == "5031362"
    | project Computer, Oct_Installed=UpdateState;
AUGTUPDATES
| join kind=inner (SEPTUPDATES) on Computer
| join kind=inner (OCTUPDATES) on Computer
```

And 2:

```
//UNION
let AUGUPDATES =
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | where KBID == "5029242"
    | project Computer, Aug_Installed=UpdateState;
let SEPTUPDATES =
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | where KBID == "5030213"
    | project Computer, Sep_Installed=UpdateState;
let OCTUPDATES =
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | where KBID == "5031362"
    | project Computer, Oct_Installed=UpdateState;
union AUGUPDATES, SEPTUPDATES, OCTUPDATES
```

Comment: Does it matter what kind of KBID it is? Are you checkin specific KBID versions?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, was using the last 3 monthly cumulative updates.

Answer (score 0):

To check installed monthly `KB updates` on virtual machines/VMS, you can use the `Kusto Query Language` query below.

**KQL Query:**

```
let InstalledData = 
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Installed"
    | project PublishedDate, Resource, Update_Status = "Installed";

let NeededData = 
    Update
    | where UpdateState == "Needed"
    | project PublishedDate, Resource, Update_Status = "Needed";

union InstalledData, NeededData
| extend UpdationDate = format_datetime(PublishedDate, 'MM-yyyy')
| summarize Installed=countif(Update_Status == "Installed"), Needed=countif(Update_Status == "Needed") by UpdationDate, Resource
| project UpdationDate, Resource, Installed, Needed
```

You can use the union operator to combine multiple datasets and display them in a table row format.

**Output:**

[image]